# Is it common for someone to say “j’espère vraiment que tu brûleras en enfer”?

Tags: argot

> J’espère vraiment que tu brûleras en enfer.

I found this insult very aggressive but I have been told that it’s the equivalent of “go to hell”. Is it really?

Comment: What research have you done to sort it out?  Please be specific as you where you are stuck.  Are you asking if it's a common  phrase or how pejorative or vulgar it is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *brûler en enfer* is just the translation of the English idiom ["burn in hell"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burn_in_hell). Another variant, besides "go to hell" is [rot in hell](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rot-in-hell-jail). It is not a typical French idiom.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard it in France.

It sounds outdated or a translation from a foreign language. The closest equivalent of "**go to hell**" would be ***Va au diable !*** or more commonly ***Casse-toi !*** / ***Va te faire voir !***

Comment: As you said, I also thought that the expression was outdated. Surprisingly, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=br%C3%BBler+en+enfer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) shows an overwhelming increase on the number of occurrences since 2000.

Comment: @Graffito A lot of foreign authors in the recent occurences but the increase might also be due to the fact we are approaching the apocalypse...

Comment: Moi je l'utilise tous les jours ;-)

Comment: @Frank Tu dois évoluer dans un environnement hostile... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Palsambleu! Va au diable, mécréant!

Comment: Oui ça a l'air d'un AI/GPTcalypse au moins.  Et la racine par un espèce de traduction de traduction ? Mon Dieu, quelle guerre cruelle ! Merci les machines, maudit bordel, debruya michaya, c'est le casse de nice people.

Comment: @Graffito my guess is that it trended at some point. Maybe it got used in a movie or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the type of deliberately outlandish and over-the-top insult young people or very close friends would exchange after a prank or nasty trick was played. Not simply the equivalent of "go to hell" and I wouldn't say it's very common either.